# external classes and PHP files in Laravel - Class not found

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-controller

I have two php files and I already created a folder called "ExternalClasses" and added the file to that folder. In my php file, I add this line:

```
namespace App\ExternalClasses;
```

and in my controller I add this line:

```
use App\ExternalClasses\CCheckMail;
```

and this is how I use it:

```
$pricesClass = new CCheckMail(); 
$email2 = ['myemail@gmail.com']; 
$prices = $pricesClass->execute ($email2); 
return view('pages.home', compact('prices'));
```

but it gave me an error:

> Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalThrowableError
>   (E_ERROR) Class 'App\ExternalClasses\CCheckMail' not found

Here is my php file (CCheckMail.php):-

```
<?php 
namespace App\ExternalClasses;
/*
*   This script was writed by Setec Astronomy - setec@freemail.it
*
*   This script is distributed  under the GPL License
*
*   This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
*   but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
*   MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
*   GNU General Public License for more details.
*
*   http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.txt
*
*/
define ('DEBUG_OK', false);
class CCheckMail
{
    var $timeout = 10;
    var $domain_rules = array ("aol.com", "bigfoot.com", "brain.net.pk", "breathemail.net",
                               "compuserve.com", "dialnet.co.uk", "glocksoft.com", "home.com",
                               "msn.com", "rocketmail.com", "uu.net", "yahoo.com", "yahoo.de");

    function _is_valid_email ($email = "") 
    { return preg_match('/^[.\w-]+@([\w-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$/', $email); }  

    function _check_domain_rules ($domain = "")
    { return in_array (strtolower ($domain), $this->domain_rules); }

    function execute ($email = "")
    {
        if (!$this->_is_valid_email ($email))
        { return false; }

        $host = substr (strstr ($email, '@'), 1);

        if ($this->_check_domain_rules ($host))
        { return false; }

        $host .= ".";

        if (getmxrr ($host, $mxhosts[0],  $mxhosts[1]) == true) 
        { array_multisort ($mxhosts[1],  $mxhosts[0]); }
        else
        {
            $mxhosts[0] = $host;
            $mxhosts[1] = 10;
        } 
        if (DEBUG_OK) { print_r ($mxhosts); }

        $port = 25;
        $localhost = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
        $sender = 'info@' . $localhost;

        $result = false;
        $id = 0;
        while (!$result && $id < count ($mxhosts[0]))
        {
            if (function_exists ("fsockopen"))
            {
                if (DEBUG_OK) { print_r ($id . " " . $mxhosts[0][$id]); }
                if ($connection = fsockopen ($mxhosts[0][$id], $port, $errno, $error, $this->timeout))
                {
                    fputs ($connection,"HELO $localhost\r\n"); // 250
                    $data = fgets ($connection,1024);
                    $response = substr ($data,0,1);
                    if (DEBUG_OK) { print_r ($data); }

                    if ($response == '2') // 200, 250 etc.
                    { 
                        fputs ($connection,"MAIL FROM:<$sender>\r\n");
                        $data = fgets($connection,1024);
                        $response = substr ($data,0,1);
                        if (DEBUG_OK) { print_r ($data); }

                        if ($response == '2') // 200, 250 etc.
                        { 
                            fputs ($connection,"RCPT TO:<$email>\r\n");
                            $data = fgets($connection,1024);
                            $response = substr ($data,0,1);
                            if (DEBUG_OK) { print_r ($data); }

                            if ($response == '2') // 200, 250 etc.
                            { 
                                fputs ($connection,"data\r\n");
                                $data = fgets($connection,1024);
                                $response = substr ($data,0,1);
                                if (DEBUG_OK) { print_r ($data); }

                                if ($response == '2') // 200, 250 etc.
                                { $result = true; }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    fputs ($connection,"QUIT\r\n"); 
                    fclose ($connection);
                    if ($result) { return true; }
                }
            }
            else
            { break; } 
            $id++;
        }  
        return false;
    }
}
?>
```

The second php file:

```
<?php 
/*
*   This script was writed by Setec Astronomy - setec@freemail.it
*
*   On row 41 of CCheckMail.php substitute the following line
*
*   if (getmxrr ($host, $mxhosts[0],  $mxhosts[1]) == true) 
*
*   with
*
*   if (getmxrr_portable ($host, $mxhosts[0],  $mxhosts[1]) == true) 
*
*   to have a fully working portable (*nix and Windows) CCheckMail class
*
*   This script is distributed  under the GPL License
*
*   This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
*   but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
*   MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
*   GNU General Public License for more details.
*
*   http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.txt
*
*/
function getmxrr_win ($hostname = "", &$mxhosts, &$weight)
{
 $weight = array();
 $mxhosts = array();
 $result = false;


 $command = "nslookup -type=mx " . escapeshellarg ($hostname);
 exec ($command, $result);
 $i = 0;
 while (list ($key, $value) = each ($result)) 
 {
    if (strstr ($value, "mail exchanger")) 
    { $nslookup[$i] = $value; $i++; }
 }

 while (list ($key, $value) = each ($nslookup)) 
 {
    $temp = explode ( " ", $value );
    $mx[$key][0] = substr($temp[3],0,-1);
    $mx[$key][1] = $temp[7];
    $mx[$key][2] = gethostbyname ( $temp[7] );
 }

 array_multisort ($mx);

 foreach ($mx as $value) 
 { 
  $mxhosts[] = $value[1];
  $weight[] = $value[0];
 } 

 $result = count ($mxhosts) > 0;
 return $result;
}

function getmxrr_portable ($hostname = "", &$mxhosts, &$weight)
{
 if (function_exists ("getmxrr"))
 { $result = getmxrr ($hostname, $mxhosts, $weight); }
 else
 { $result = getmxrr_win ($hostname, $mxhosts, $weight); }
 return $result; 
}
?>
```

[image]

Comment: Can you add the file tree structure too?  We need to check your folder hierarchy and naming to ensure that the file is in the right place.  We don't need to see so much code.  Just file system, name spaces, and class name will do.

Comment: I update the question with project structure

Comment: Hmm... the PSR4 is pretty specific about naming.  What's up with getmxrr.php?  That's not psr4 and should not be in that area of the file system.  I can't say that's your problem, but it's not gonna help ~ especially when you're trying to `composer dump-auto` and seeing your project blow up.

Comment: Functions declared in `getmxrr.php` are not used in `CCheckMail` class, so that file is not relevant to the question.

Comment: PSR4 is relevant to your project.  If you're having symphony autoload() problems ... you'll want to be following PSR4 in all the directories/* listed in your composer.json file.  So ... just humour me and fix it.

Comment: FYI the standard way of adding a helper library of functions to make an `abstract` class in the app namespace, then call the functions statically like this `\App\Helpers::myFunk(...)`

Comment: so how can I fix it?

Comment: @TarekAdam Firstly, I am not the author of this question. Secondly, that file can be whatever, it won't do anything. I suggest you read on autoload in PHP in general before trying to answer questions. The problem here is definitely a typo somewhere. It can be even a trailing space in folder name or something sneaky as that.

Comment: actually, getmxrr.php and CCheckMail.php are downloaded from internet. Have you tried to include it in your project and check if it's working? may it will help me to identify problem.

Comment: @d3jn I agree typo is the most likely.  So stay calm and code on.

Comment: @Miss.Nada yes, works on clean Laravel 5.6 project.

Comment: @d3jn has put me off trying to be helpful.  I'm out.  Good luck with it. Miss Nada.

Comment: You didn't by chance set the namespace of your app to something else besides `App`, for example by using the command `php artisan app:name`?

Comment: I think it was type issue, now I am getting this error fsockopen(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: nodename nor servname provided, or not known. Is because I am using XAMPP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just type `composer dumpautoload -o` in your terminal.

Comment: I use these commands and now my whole project is not working!! $ php artisan clear-compiled 
$ composer dump-autoload
$ php artisan optimize

Comment: this command autoloads your classes in your app dir and your new classes should be readable right now .. so if you have another error it's not from this command bro ?!!

Comment: This is the error I got after running the commands: Fatal error: Uncaught RuntimeException: A facade root has not been set. in /Users/Nada/Desktop/nadalaravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php:220 Stack trace: #0 /Users/Nada/Desktop/nadalaravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php(397):

Comment: What is the inside bootstrap/app.php

is look like that

`$app = new Illuminate\Foundation\Application(
    realpath(__DIR__ . '/../')
);`

Answer (score 0):

It was typing error, I created a new project and redo my coding and it's working fine.